Estimating PDF from historical data
Imagine we have a set of points through which we want to fit a probability distribution.
The classic approach would be either:

Parametric estimation (we assume a specific PDF and try to estimate the PDF parameters such that the PDF best fits the data points)

KDE (no assumption about a specific PDF, we just fit the data subject to constraints so that the end result satisfies the conditions for a valid PDF)


Question: Suppose I want to get a parametric PDF, but I don't know a-priory which specific PDF it should be. Is there a known approach to solve such a problem? (either a paper presenting the mathematical solution to this problem or a known software package / module that does it with brute-force).
To make things more complicated, I have a time-series whereby on each day, there is a set of data points through which I want to fit a parametric PDF: on any day, the PDF parameters could be different, but ideally, I want to describe this time-series via a single parametric PDF (where the parameters can vary in time).

You'd probably start with using what known information you have. Is it only positive values? Then you probably would exclude a Gaussian. Do you have theoretical reasons to believe it would be skewed? Symmetric? etc. - these can all inform the choice of distribution. Do you have any models suggesting a certain type of distribution? And so on. Also consider, what are you actually trying to achieve with this? This will also inform what kind of approximation you are willing to allow.

Good tips @AlexJ, thank you!
